# How can I keep track data after offline or reconnection with meteor-streamer?

Tags: meteor

Sorry for my English. I use [RocketChat/meteor-streamer](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/rocketchat:streamer) in my app. On readme page, in downsides section written that "Since the library don't keep track of data, you will not receive lost data while offline after reconnection. But we have an event to notify you on reconnections passing the latest record received so you can call a method to verify and get the missing data." What method or event I must to call, to keep track data state? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be [a function `onReconnect`](https://github.com/RocketChat/meteor-streamer/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reconnect) for registering handlers for that event.